# Select particular element by position in Html Agility Pack

Tags: html, xpath, html-agility-pack

Let suppose i have following html code

```
<ul>
<li>First</li>
<li>Second</li>
<li>Third</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>Apple</li>
<li>Orange</li>
<li>Pear</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>Red</li>
<li>Blue</li>
<li>Black</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>Circle</li>
<li>Square</li>
<li>Rectangle</li>
</ul>
```

Now i have to select second ul in Html Agility Pack
how it is possible
now i have following code

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul//li")
```

Note:- i cannot give any specify class to above ul tags or any kind of attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way, to get the element by identifying it as the 2nd `<ul>` element within the same parent :

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[2]")
```

or if you want the corresponding `<li>`s instead :

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[2]/li")
```

Comment: One thing that caught me out is this array is 1 based, not 0 based (just in case anyone else misses that)